# PHP: Find common repeating string?

Tags: php, string, key, repeat

I have this situation in PHP.  I have an array that has these keys for example, wires-1, wires-2, wires-3.  I need a function or way for my program to read these keys, and find that the common word is wires?  How would that be accomplished in PHP?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What would constitute a "common word"?  String starts with $word?  $word appears before a $delimiter_character in $string?  Be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how an autocomplete's functionality works, this is similar to your approach.

I'm sure there's plenty of source codes for autocomplete on google

Answer (score 0):

For the string value of every key in your array:

1. Throw away all non-alpha characters, i.e. leave only letters such that `ctype_alpha($remaining_text)` should return `true`.
2. Keep an array with the found words as *keys*, and their frequencies as *values*, as such:

   ```
   $array = new array();
   function found_word($word)
   {  global $array;
      if(!isset($array[$word])) { $array[$word] = 1; }
      else { $array[$word]++; }
   }
   ```

   Only nicer ;)
3. Sort the array in reverse by using `arsort($array);`
4. `$array` now contains the most found words as its first elements.

Answer (score 0):

1. you would have to create every possible suffix of every string you have.
2. create a map for every suffix you found
3. count the occurence of every suffix in your string array

you can modify the performance with f.ex. limiting the suffix length